# which are the technical names for these verb transforms?

Tags: verbs

what are the Japanese, and English, technical terms for these verb transforms:

読める、買える、書ける、...

and this:
読まれる、買われる、書かれる、...

and this:
読ませる、買わせる、書かせる、...

Is there a standard term that textbooks use to call the changing of verb stems into those 3 different forms? "Verb conjugation" sounds natural, however "conjugate" does not sound correct in the context.

What do Japanese students call the changing of verbs into those 3 different forms?

thanks.

Comment: Japanese as taught to non-native speakers (日本語教育) usually describes these differently than Japanese school grammar (国文法).  For instance, in the latter, 読まれる isn't a single inflectional form.  Instead, it's the inflectional form 読ま, plus the inflectable suffix れる.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 読める、買える、書ける、...　→　**Potential Form (可能形)**
>
> and this: 読まれる、買われる、書かれる、...　→　**Passive form (受け身形)**
>
> and this: 読ませる、買わせる、書かせる、...　→　**Causative form (使役【しえき】形)**

"Conjugation" is correct, and you can say `動詞の活用（形）`.

Comment: I'd never heard the term `受動態` before, but apparently they are equivalent.  The `形` though means "form", so `受動態` seems like the more general "passive voice".

Comment: @kinyo Well, they're *almost* direct translations.  They mean *present continuous* ***form***, *future* ***form***, and *past perfect* ***form***...

Comment: @kinyo:  Sounds about right.  Here's what my dictionary says.  `使役の助動詞「させる」の未然形＋受身の助動詞「られる」`.